# Finding the right stepper motor holding torque for and X and Y gantry pick and place moving back and forth

Tags: torque, stepper-motor, linear-motors

**X axis**

Force = mgu
M = mass of plate
g = gravity
u = coefficient of friction

(7kg)(9.81m/s)(0.5) = 34N

Torque = fxd
F = force
d = radius of pulley

T = (34N)(4mm) = 136 mNm
(**Stepper Motor, NEMA 17, 27 in.-oz. Maximum Holding Torque.) Igot this for the x axis.

**Y-axis**

Force = mgu
M = mass of the plate
g = gravity
u = coefficient of friction

(4kg)(9.81m/s)(0.5) = 20 N

Torque = fxd
F = force
d = radius of pulley

T = (20N)(4mm) = 80 mNm.
(**NEMA 14, 20 in.-oz. Maximum Holding Torque) I got this for the y-axis).

*I need help on this calculations, I don't know if I'm right.

Comment: Is that a single, Queen or King?

Comment: I mean the mass of plate where the components is going to be place like 4x6

Comment: Don't forget your desired acceleration. If your motors only just match the force required to overcome friction then it will mean that it will just sit and only ever be able to maintain whatever velocity you give it when you nudge it, as if it were a frictionless surface. You need enough torque to overcome friction, then enough extra torque on top of that to accelerate to speed. Once at speed, the acceleration torque dials back to zero so only the torque to overcome friction remains to simulate a object in motion remaining in motion without friction.

Comment: 4*6 mm, cm, m, inches, feet, furlongs?

Comment: It's about 4by6 in.